# How to zip all files including hidden files to zip file using linux command?

Tags: command, zip, htaccess

I have linux hosting and wanted to zip everything in one single zip file but all time .htaccess file is excluded and other hidden files are not adding to zip file.

Comment: It's better if you don't create [tarbombs](http://www.linfo.org/tarbomb.html).

Comment: How are you creating the zip file?

Comment: Use the dot to include current directory:

    $ cd /path/to/dir/project
    $ zip -r project.zip .

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way is to tell your shell to include hidden files in globs. With bash this is done with `shopt -s dotglob`.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose, you try something like

```
zip /path/to/your/zipfile *
```

but `*` doesn't match filenames starting with a dot. But `?` matches a dot, so `?*` matches all file names, including those starting with a dot. Unfortunally it also matches `..`, the parent directory, so do

```
zip /path/to/your/zipfile ??*
```

This will match everything in the current directory.

Comment: Not in my case. Using Version 5.1.8(1)-release.

Comment: Wildcard expansion is done by the shell, the `zip` version is irrelevant. What is your shell and what files are missing in the archive?

Comment: I am sorry. I already stated the version, but forgot to mention bash. It is the version of bash I am using. Thank you.

Comment: `??*` won't match any single-character names.  That may or may not be a problem, but it's worth saying explicitly so users can check whether that's needed.  `??* [^.]` might be better for those cases.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to note is if you are using a wildcard such as `tar -cvpzf your_zip.tgz *` it will not include hidden files. However, if you specify the directory such as `tar -cvpzf your_zip.tgz /path/to/dir` it will work. Or moreover, if you would like to run in your current directory:

```
tar -cvpfz your_zip.tgz --exclude=*.tgz .
```

Comment: They did say "zip" several times in the title, question, and tags, so a 'tar' answer a little off-target. Your idea is almost there, too -- when given a wildcard source, tar would actually include hidden files of *subdirectories*, just not (by default) of the current directory.